Mouse stops working when starting a Guest in Virtualbox
Sometimes when i start a Guest in VirtualBox (Ubuntu 22.04 or Windows 7) the mouse stops working on Host system (also Ubuntu 22.04). The is no mouse visible. Unplug the usb dongle or trying an other Mouse doesn't work. I have a VNC-Server (TigerVNC) running on the host and here the mouse also doesn't work. So it looks like its not a hardware problem.
I can't check whether the mouse works inside the running VM.
The problem occurs not every time i start the VM.
